# How to correct a display problem when inserting a row in a JavaFX grid?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to insert a new JavaFX bean in a grid using an "insert" button. Everything is fine, except for a display problem. After insertion, a "ghost selection" is displayed lower in the grid, as shown in this screenshot. In this example, a fourth section bean was added and selected as requested. But a fake selection appears 10 lines under the last real bean, where no bean is set for this row.

[image: Screenshot of a ghost selection]

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior? Any clue how get rid of this ghost selection? Here is what the code for the insert button looks like:

```
@FXML
private Button insert;

...

insert.setOnAction(event -> {
    JfxBean newBean = createBean();
    tableView.getItems().add(newBean);
    int index = tableView.getItems().indexOf(newBean);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tableView.requestFocus();
    tableView.scrollTo(index);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().focus(index);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(index);
  };
```

Comment: From the tests I did so far, this strange behavior is related to selected model. I've been able to generate a ghost selection by only selecting a cell in the grid. This problem is not specifically related to insertion.

Comment: It seems that adding `tableView.refresh();` immediately after `tableView.getSelectionModel().select(index);` corrects the problem. I'll make more tests to validate this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [javaFX-8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/), `SelectionModel.java` does not expose any `focus()` method. `FocusModel.java` does instead. Therefore JVM will fail to compile your presented code.

Below is a possible solution:

```
insert.setOnAction(event -> {
    JfxBean newBean = createBean();
    tableView.getItems().add(newBean);
    int index = tableView.getItems().indexOf(newBean);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tableView.requestFocus();
    tableView.scrollTo(index);
    // below line is the amendment
    tableView.getFocusModel().focus(index);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(index);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this amendment didn't change the behavior, but I'll keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, adding `tableView.refresh()` corrected this weird behavior. No more ghost selection.